# Publishing failed after update to wordpress 5.0

Tags: wordpress

I downloaded a fresh latest Wordpress from the wordpress.org and installed it. However, While I create new pages and tried to publish it then I am not able to publish as it shows an error.
Publishing fails after update to WordPress 5.0

Comment: Could it be due to the new editor (Gutenberg)?

Comment: What error does it show when you try to publish? If you install a fresh copy of [wordpress 4.9](https://wordpress.org/download/releases/) does it still happen?

Answer (score 0):

In your Wordpress dashboard, under Settings > Permalinks, click on Save changes. Then try to publish your page/post again.

If that doesn't work, install the Classic Editor plugin from the Wordpress repository (this will disable Gutenberg), and see if that resolves the issue.

If the above does (or doesn't), then I suggest you enable Wordpress debugging and see what the actual error is.

Debugging in Wordpress - https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by following these steps:

1. Logged in to Wordpress.
2. Navigated to Plugins -> Add New -> Installed Classic Editor